# parted - Completely overwrite USB device

Tags: debian, partition, gparted, parted

After using Kubuntu for a few months, I wanted to install a lower level OS, e.g. Debian. I used the [Debian manual](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch04s03.html.en#usb-copy-isohybrid),  by writing the ISO directly to the USB.

Now GParted doesn't see the USB, fdisk says inappropriate ioctl, and parted says unrecognized disk label. Is there a command to completely overwrite the file system on the USB?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wipe the drive with (as root) `wipefs --all /dev/sdX`. Where `X` in `sdX` is the drive you want to erase. Be **careful that you are choosing the right drive**!

---

After that; I always use the `dd` command when writing to USB sticks. Like so:

```
sudo dd if=/home/<user>/Downloads/<debian>.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=4M;
```

Where `X` in `sdX` is the device in question.

It will **completely overwrite everything** in `sdX`, so (again!) make sure you are writing to the correct drive!

Read more about `dd` [here](https://superuser.com/questions/351814/how-to-copy-an-iso-image-onto-usb-with-dd#351815).

Comment: "No space left on device". Am I messing up the command: 'dd if=/home/joe/Downloads/DebianKDELive.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=4M;' as su.

Comment: Never seen that before! Can you wipe the drive with `wipefs --all /dev/sdX` and then try again?

Comment: Oh, I feel so stupid! The device was actually sdc, which I would have sworn was sdb. I think in the end wipefs was what kickstarted gparted to recognize to USB. Add it to the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Ok. Glad you solved the issue. Added information on `wipefs` in my post.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a good time to use [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).

Not only will this allow you to remove and add a new partition table, but it may also help you recover the previous. There is a good step by step [here](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step), and another [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/recover-data-and-partitions-for-free-with-testdisk/).